# Variable in subprocess

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

Is there any way to pass variable in subprocess? This didn't work.

```
subprocess.check_output(["cat test.txt | grep %s"], shell=True) %(variable)
```

Comment: The `%` operator has to go after the string it is operating on. `"cat test.txt | grep %s"%variable` . You have got it off some place to the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `str.format`:

```
"cat test.txt | grep {}".format(variable)
```

Or using old style formatting put the variable directly after.

```
"cat test.txt | grep %s"%variable
```

Your list is also redundant when using shell=True:

```
subprocess.check_output("cat fable.txt | grep %s" %variable, shell=True)
```

If you were using a list of args  without shell = True, you could use Popen:

```
from subprocess import Popen,PIPE
p1 = Popen(["cat","text.txt"], stdout=PIPE)
p2 = Popen(["grep", variable], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
p1.stdout.close()  
out,err = p2.communicate()
p1.wait()
print(out)
```

Comment: How will it work if I want to have multiple variables ?

Comment: multiple variables will be exactly the same, `"cat test.txt | grep {} {}".format(variable,variable2)`, same idea using "%s", I prefer str.format as I think it is more obvious.

Comment: thanks, another question, if I want to awk multiple colons of a command and put in multiple variables. Is there a simple way of doing that instead of running the subprocess for every varaible ?

Comment: can you give me an example?

Comment: @user3270211: to escape shell metacharacters such as `'\`$!`, you could use `pipes.quote(variable)`. `cat` is useless here, you could pass the file to `grep` directly: `output = check_output(['grep', variable, 'fable.txt'])` (note: no `shell=True`). It is also simple to implement `grep`-like functionality in pure Python (search a substring, use regexes, etc).

Comment: In general, to emulate `a | b` you could also use `b = Popen('b', stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE); a = Popen('a', stdout=b.stdin); out = b.communicate()[0]; a.wait()`

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, thanks did not realize I missed the `.wait()`.